# saving value of textbox on keypress event

Tags: jquery, ajax

Good morning to everyone. Thanks for visiting my question.
How can I save value of textbox on enter key and, when user presses up key, so that when user press the up arrow key, it loads the value of the last content in the textbox.

it here my code so far, but it doesnt work unfortunately..

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var lstMsg;
    $('#myTextbox').bind("keyup", function(e){
         if ( e.keyCode == 39){
              $(this).val($(lstMsg).val());
         }
         if ( e.keyCode == 13){
              lstMsg.val($(this).val());
         }
    });
 });
```

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

`lstMsg` being a variable does not have a `.val()` method defined on it.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
   var lstMsg;
   $('#myTextbox').bind("keyup", function(e){
        if ( e.keyCode == 39){
          $(this).val(lstMsg);
        }
        if ( e.keyCode == 13){
          lstMsg = $(this).val();
        }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think Best way is this :

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#myTextbox').bind("keyup", function(e)
    {
        if ( e.keyCode == 38)
        {
            $(this).val($(this).data('last_val'));
        }
        if ( e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            $(this).data('last_val',$(this).val())
        }
    });
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Davood/cdzWH/

Answer (score 0):

Store and get the textarea value using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

**to store the value**

```
$(this).data('x',this.value);
```

**To get the stored value**

```
$(this).data('x');
```